# 2.3 Nopcommerce theme updated to a 3.0?

Tags: css, themes, updates, nopcommerce

I'm newbie in nopcommerce, and I have to do this: update a site with nopcommerce 2.2 to a nopcommerce 3.0 but just the theme, I mean, I have 2 sites already design but I want to theme the 2.2 site with the one in 3.0.

If it was a simple html page, just copying the css's would be enough. I try that but it's not working, the site is not responsive.

I'm thinking in checking view by view to change everything that is different...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice idea. But the version 3.0 is far feature rich than 2.2. So does the theme. Most of the new features wont be able to support in 2.2. So just copy over will not work.

Best approach i would say is to start with an existing theme of 2.2 and add additional features such as responsive designs etc on top. This will be a bit of wild ride, but it will work.